# Talend Big-Data tMSSQLBulkExec Bulk Update returns Identity column 'PK_column' contains invalid INCREMENT

Tags: java, sql-server, talend

I am working on an ETL Process that inserts new data and updates changed data from a staging table into a dimension table in a SQL Server Database.

I have set up the table in SQL Server so that it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [schema].[dim_learning_activity](
    [dim_learning_activity_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [activity_fk] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [code] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [label] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [date_last_update] [date] NULL,
    [start_date] [date] NULL,
    [end_date] [date] NULL,
    [active] [int] NULL,
    [est_cred_hours] [float] NULL,
    [ConType_Name] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Txt1] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [TechnicalCourse] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [TechnicalCourseCategory] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [CreationDt] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dim_learning_activity_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [dim_learning_activity_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_dim_learning_activity] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [activity_fk] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Where you can see the dim_learning_activity_id is the Primary Key.

Below is the setup I currently have in Talend:

[image: Talend Layout]

The file that Talend outputs is in the proper format (columns delimited by "%%" and rows by "\n"):

```
5458%%108129%%Learning Item Name%%108129%%%%Curriculum%%2018-05-11%%%%%%1%%0.5%%Products (Technical Content)%%Technical%%Technical%%Delta%%2018-05-11
```

Which equates to:

```
dim_learning_activity_id = 5458
activity_fk = 108129
name = Learning Item Name
code = 108129
description = null
label = Curriculum
date_last_update = 2018-05-11
start_date = null
end_date = null
active = 1
est_cred_hours = 0.5
ConType_Name = Products (Technical Content)
Txt1 = Technical
TechnicalCourse = Technical
TechnicalCourseCategory = Delta
CreationDt = 2018-05-11
```

The record is already in the dimension table, but it will not update with the Talend tMSSQLBulkExec with the Bulk Update option selected.

I have tried completely wiping the table and starting from scratch with it and still receive this error, even on a fresh run of the job, when the table is blank and all it is doing is inserting, the Update errors out with the same error.

I have also tried updating on the activity_fk (System of Record ID), which results in the same error.

Please let me know if there is more information you need to help.

Comment: Not showing the full job. Do you have a `tMSSQLConnection`?

Comment: Yes, there is a tMSSQLConnection just above the **Insert or Update LMS activities dimension** SubJob. It is pointed to the correct server and completes the Insert just fine.

Also, the tMSSQLCommit component after **Insert** is NOT set to close the connection, but the tMSSQLCommit after **Update** is set to close the connection (it just isn't making it to that component before failure)

Comment: If I understand correctly. All subjobs should be handled within a single transaction?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean, and how mine differs from that? I have one "MSSQLConnection" at the beginning witch opens up the DB for the query which creates the Bulk Files, one "MSSQLCommit" after the "insert" subjob and an "MSSQLCommit" with "Close Connection" after the "update" subjob. The FTP is just to move the Bulk File to the MSSQL Server so that the server can read it.

Comment: t_Connection will create a connection and open a global transaction. If you are committing iteratively, you need to disable auto commit. _"Note that if you need to commit each statement as an individual transaction, you have to use the Auto Commit function available in the connection component."_

Comment: @MarvinWordWeaverParsons Are you also trying to update the Identity column in your Update statement? This might be the reason of your error. Please check.

Comment: @Mayanak No, I'm not updating the Identity Column, I'm trying to update BASED ON the identity column, so I am passing the Identity Value through to the MSSQLBulkOutput. Should I not pass the Key? If not, how does it know which record to update?

Comment: @Kermit, I will check the Auto Commit and get back with you in a few days. (Currently focused on GDPR touches).

Comment: Thank you all for your help. We have decided to stick with MySQL, as it is easier to manage, doesn't come with all of these caveats, and is free.

For the record, there was no solution found to this problem.